# How to add a ZedGraph programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, zedgraph

I want to add a [ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph) when I click a button, but the ZedGraph is not coming up when I click my button. Here is my button click handler:

```
 ZedGraphControl zg1 = new ZedGraphControl(); 
 zg1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
 GraphPane myPane = new GraphPane();
 BarItem myBar = new BarItem("Bar1");
 myBar.AddPoint(1, 10);
 myBar.AddPoint(2, 20);
 myBar.Bar.Fill = new Fill(Color.AliceBlue, Color.White, Color.AliceBlue);
 zg1.AxisChange();
 zg1.Invalidate();

 zg1.Show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing that jumps out at me is that I don't see you [adding your new `Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) to your Container Object wether it be a `Form` or a `Panel`. Also you are not associating your `Pane` or your `Bar` to your `ZedGraphControl`

Try Something like this

```
ZedGraphControl zg1 = new ZedGraphControl();
zg1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
zg1.GraphPane = new GraphPane();

BarItem myBar = new BarItem("Bar1");
myBar.AddPoint(1, 10);
myBar.AddPoint(2, 20);
myBar.Bar.Fill = new Fill(Color.AliceBlue, Color.White, Color.AliceBlue);

zg1.GraphPane.CurveList.Add(myBar);


zg1.AxisChange();
zg1.Invalidate();

zg1.Show();
this.Controls.Add(zg1);
```